# What test should I use?

Tags: regression, wilcoxon-signed-rank, kendall-tau

I have a set of n objects being tested for characteristics c1 and c2. Using a two-output classifier, I obtain rankings R1 and R2 for each of my objects, which represent its likelihood of c1 or c2. Are the rankings for the two characteristics correlated, or are they indistinguishable?

Initially I looked at the Wilcoxon Signed-Rank Test, but that moves from unranked data to rankings and I think I should use something else. Any suggestions?

--------------------Edit-------------------------------------

Update per the suggestion of one commenter. I tested my data with a linear regression of R1 vs R2 for all objects. I got data back which generally looks like the plot below. In one data set I have 2000 points and they cover every inch of the plot. Not at all helpful in predicting a trend or relationship. My best R^2 value is .24 and most of them are around .09.

[image: Example of data similar to my own]

On one hand, that may be a sort of answer. The regression shows that the relationship between the two characteristics is non existant. If they were closely correlated, even in a negative correlation, it would show that I could predict the presense of c1 by finding c2. This seems to suggest that no, they are totally unrelated. Agian, however, I'm not sure that this is strong enough proof that the rankings aren't substantially similar.

I would still value some feedback.

---------------------EDIT---------------------------------

I have been continuing to look at a variety of methods which might serve my purpose. One of these which comes close is Kendall's Tau. It works for exactly my purpose of comparing two sets of rankings, HOWEVER, it is geared to look for correlation and reject the possibility of correlation if the agreement is not high enough. That is exactly opposite of what I'm looking for.

As an example, I ran one of my data sets through and with 240 data points, the Tau is .19. This corresponds to a Z value of 4.4 which would seem to indicate that they are correlated. Another data set with 950 data points produces a Tau of .03. This corresponds to a Z value of 1.5. Basically, I can say that the first set does appear to be correlated, but I can't say that the second data set is not. I can only reject the null hypothesis that they are not the same. Those don't appear to be equivalent.

Comment: your question is a bit vague.

i am not aware of a formally-correct test for what i *think* you are asking. but have you scatter-plotted the data with R1 on the x-axis and R2 on the y-axis? if the rankings are similar, there should be a high correlation. you might even conduct a simple linear regression of R2 on R1 and vice-versa as a form of data exploration.

Comment: I'd be happy to clarify. What part is unclear? Incidentally I tried a linear regression of R1 vs R2 on a few of the data sets I have been working on. I updated my original post.

Comment: It does look like there's not much of a relationship between your predictions R1 and R2. Of course, since this is just your prediction, it doesn't mean that c1 is unrelated to c2; it might just be that your predictive method doesn't incorporate the factors that are similar between c1 and c2.

Comment: @CloudyGloudy That is true. So this is something akin to testing for one medical condition and correlating that with a test for a second one. The question still remains is this test sufficiently robust to say with any confidence that the test results are or are not similar?

Comment: Your second edit has me a bit confused; I might just not understand your wording though. Is your hope to show that there is NO association between the two rankings, or that there is some association? With Kendall's Tau, the null hypothesis is no association. You can show evidence of association between the two rankings if you reject the null hypothesis. But it's impossible to prove NO association, as you mentioned -- the best you can do there is to say with high confidence that the association is very weak if there is any.

Comment: My thoughts from looking at your data/statistics are that there probably is very little correlation between the two tests, if any. Of course, whether this is practically useful or not depends on your application; in some applications even the most minute correlation is worth detecting.